# Stream has already been operated upon or closed - Java 8

Tags: java, exception, filter, java-8, java-stream

Why I have next exception?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.<init>(AbstractPipeline.java:203)...
com.search.offer.OffersSelector.isGood(OffersSelector.java:23)
```

How change the code to fix it?

```
Stream<String> titleExclusions = ResourceUtility.contentToUtf8TreeSet("+.txt").
        stream().filter(item -> item.length() == 0).collect(Collectors.toSet()).stream();
//...
titleExclusions.filter(tittle::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() == 0;//line 23
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: You can't operate on a stream twice. Presumably you already operated on `titleExclusions` in `//...`.

Comment: By the way, you don’t need to collect into a `Set` all the time (otherwise, if you want to do your work with `Set`s, just do it without switching to the Stream API in-between). Since your elements are distinct already, `collect(Collectors.toSet()).size()` is just the same as `count()`, but `stream.filter(tittle::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() == 0` is the same as just `stream.noneMatch(tittle::contains)` anyway…

Comment: There is a lot of seemingly unnecessary complication in this code, but it should work, unless there is something important in the omitted part of the code.

Comment: Not storing stream instances in variables will greatly help avoiding the “stream has already been operated upon or closed” error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't operate on Streams more than once so you are better off using Collections as these can be used more than once.

```
Set<String> titleExclusions = ResourceUtility.contentToUtf8TreeSet("+.txt")
                                             .stream()
                                             .filter(item -> !item.isEmpty())
                                             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
// uses titleExclusions 
boolean noMatches = titleExclusions.stream()
                                   .noneMatch(tittle::contains);
// uses titleExclusions again.
```

Note: I assume you wanted the non-blank lines from your source file instead of the sets of blank ones. `filter` takes a `Predicate` of what is retained rather than what is discarded.

Thank you @Holger for simplifying the second statement.

Comment: `.filter(tittle::contains).findAny().isPresent()` is really `anyMatch(tittle::contains)`

Comment: @Tunaki: …and `!(titleExclusions.stream().filter(tittle::contains).findAny() .isPresent())` is the same as `titleExclusions.stream().noneMatch(tittle::contains)`.